# Nested Insert into and select statement

Tags: mysql

I have following structur in my MySql database:

1 Table called reports and 1 Table called product

I want now to insert into reports based on a selection of products. The error i get is following:

Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row  0.000 sec

In my last select statement (only select, no insert) i solved this error with the Keyword "IN" but in this case it dont work. Here is the query i have so far (which produces the error)

```
INSERT INTO reports (report_date, report_emploee, report_content, report_art, report_adressnummer)
VALUES(
NOW(), 
'UpdateMaster', 
'content', 
'AutoUpdate' , 
(SELECT product.product_adressnummer 
FROM product 
WHERE product.product_name='testproduct'
AND product.product_version='2.50c' 
AND product_updateDatum >= '2015-12-11'));
```

I tried to create an array with my select statement and then iterate over it during insert into reports, but i dont get it in sql. All informations online combine sql and php to get it work.

If i would execute the query it would look like this:

```
report_date=today
report_emploee='UpdateMaster'
report_content='content'
report_art='AutoUpdate'
report_adressnummer=123,456,789,310,...
```

but it should execute like this:

```
report_date=today
report_emploee='UpdateMaster'
report_content='content'
report_art='AutoUpdate'
report_adressnummer=123

report_date=today
report_emploee='UpdateMaster'
report_content='content'
report_art='AutoUpdate'
report_adressnummer=456

report_date=today
report_emploee='UpdateMaster'
report_content='content'
report_art='AutoUpdate'
report_adressnummer=789
```

.......

You solution affected 0 rows in sql table.

If i execute this query:

```
SELECT contact.contact_vorname, contact.contact_nachname, contact.contact_eMail
FROM contact 
WHERE contact.contact_adressnummer IN
(SELECT product.product_adressnummer 
FROM product 
WHERE product.product_name='toolstar®TestLX'
AND product.product_version='2.50c' 
AND product_updateDatum >= '2015-12-11');
```

it returns 8 rows and your solution should also affect 8 rows, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is when you try and insert the result of

```
SELECT product.product_adressnummer 
FROM product 
WHERE product.product_name='testproduct'
AND product.product_version='2.50c' 
AND product_updateDatum >= '2015-12-11'
```

into your table. As this returns more than one record, you cannot insert it where one record should be. `IN` does not solve the problem as this does not prevent more than one record being returned.

If you want to insert a record for every record returned you could use:

```
INSERT INTO 
    reports (report_date, report_emploee, report_content, report_art, report_adressnummer)
SELECT
    NOW(), 
    'UpdateMaster', 
    'content', 
    'AutoUpdate' ,
    product.product_adressnummer 
FROM product 
WHERE product.product_name='testproduct'
AND product.product_version='2.50c' 
AND product_updateDatum >= '2015-12-11'
```

Comment: I added some mor infomations!

Comment: The answer is the same! Your SELECT statement returns multiple rows, and you are trying to insert several rows into a single field, which doesn't work. In the final query you select several records, but don't try and insert them anywhere, which is why it works. Try this answer and see what it returns.

Comment: Ok yes it works thank you. But could you please explain how it works to use insert into and select 'UpdateMaster'? How can i select a String?

Comment: For strings, it will select the string for every row the query returns. For SELECT INTO, I would look into the documentation and tutorials, I won't be as good at explaining as that.