# Inserting sqlite data based on join and case

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select, case

I have 2 tables: **weekly_scores** and **team** in a sqlite database (SQLite Version 3.32.2)

- Weekly_scores has *team_id* and a *goal_differential* that contains the number of goals that the team won by that week. team has *team.id* for different teams
- I want to categorize teams in the **team** table based on the maximum winning goals during the season.

  - If *goal_differential* < 2, then *team.skill* = low
  - If *goal_differential* >= 2, then *team.skill* = high

I want to return the maximum goal differential for each team in the **weekly_scores** table and categorize the *skill* in the **team** table by the above criteria.

I based my code off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222714/nested-insert-into-and-select-statement) and [this website](https://www.sqlshack.com/case-statement-in-sql/)

```
insert into team(skill)
values(
case 
    select max(weekly_scores.goal_differential) as max_count
    from weekly_scores
    left join team
    on weekly_scores.team_id = team.id
    where weekly_scores.goal_differential is not NULL
    group by team.id;
when max_count < 2 then team.skill = low
when max_count >= 2 then team.skill = high
end);
```

I get the following error

```
Result: near "select": syntax error  
At line 8:  
insert into team(skill)  
values(  
case   
    select
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Is the table team empty? Why do you insert only the column skill?

Comment: The team table is filled with data related to the team (e.g., city, year incorporated). The skill column is based on the data found in the weekly_scores table

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the table `team` and not insert new rows.
Use a correlated subquery:

```
update team 
set skill = coalesce(
  (
    select case when max(w.goal_differential) < 2 then 'low' else 'high' end 
    from weekly_scores w
    where w.team_id = team.id and w.goal_differential is not NULL 
  ), 
  skill
)
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks! What function does coalesce perform?

Comment: @user2466888 coalesce() returns the 1st non null of its arguments: https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce

Answer (score 0):

You coudl try insert select this way

```
insert into team(id, skill)
select t.id
, case when t.max_count < 2 then 'low' else 'high' end 
from (
    select team.id, max(weekly_scores.goal_differential) as max_count
    from weekly_scores
    left join team
    on weekly_scores.team_id = team.id
    where weekly_scores.goal_differential is not NULL
    group by team.id
) t
```

Comment: I tried this answer and received the following error message.                                 Execution finished with errors.
Result: near ";": syntax error
At line 9                                                                                                                                         I also tried adding the semi-colon after the final parentheses but got a similar message.

Comment: wrrong semicolon in subquery ..  removed  answer updated --